# Simplifying this django query - Have django obtain instances based on values

Tags: python, django, model

So I currently have this django query. The first two statements are needed in order to obtain the 3rd statement. My question is if there is a way to only use the 3rd statements without using the first two statements.

```
 #patient_name and quest are two strings
 patientobj = modelPatient.objects.get(patient_name=patient_name)
 questobj = modelInterviewQuestion.objects.get(question=quest)
 answer   = modelInterviewAnswer.objects.get(patients=patientobj, questions=questobj)
```

I know I could do something like this

```
answer   = modelInterviewAnswer.objects.get(patients= modelPatient.objects.get(patient_name=patient_name), questions= modelInterviewQuestion.objects.get(question=quest))
```

but I was wondering if there is anything simpler ?

Here are the relationship between models

```
class modelPatient(models.Model):
    patient_name       = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    patient_sex        = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    patient_image      = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', 

class modelInterviewQuestion(models.Model):
    question      = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)

class modelInterviewAnswer(models.Model):
    patients = models.ForeignKey(modelPatient)
    questions = models.ForeignKey(modelInterviewQuestion)
    patient_response = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
```

Comment: Please provide relationship between models.

Comment: Sure let me update the question

Comment: @Darshit just updated my question with more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this.

```
answer = modelInterviewAnswer.objects.get(patients__patient_name=patient_name, questions__question=quest)
```

Please go through this documentation to know how to write query that [span relationship.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

I want to draw you attention at naming convention.

1. Don't prefix model name with `model`, for example `modelPatient` should be only `Patient`.
2. Don't need to write `patient_<field_name>` in model. It should be only `<field_name>`

For example your `Paitent` model should look like

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

Follow same instructions for other models too.

```
class InterviewQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)

class InterviewAnswer(models.Model):
    patients = models.ForeignKey(modelPatient)
    interview_questions = models.ForeignKey(modelInterviewQuestion)
    patient_response = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
```

So Your query will be.

```
answer = InterviewAnswer.objects.get(patients__name=patient_name, interview_questions__question=quest)
```

Comment: I think you need 2 underscores in questions_question (i.e. "questions__question")

Comment: @Darshit I also think we need two underscores. Ill test this and post back

Comment: @JamesFranco You should also not give a field a plural name (`patients`, `_questions`) if they reference only a single instance.